# Accessing a custom attribute from within a compound control's xml layout file (ie. no Java/Kotlin code)

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls

I have a Compound View with two custom attributes. I use the control like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mycompany.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:numberTint="@android:color/white"
        app:letterTint="@android:color/black" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The attrs.xml file:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyView">
    <attr name="numberTint" format="color"/>
    <attr name="letterTint" format="color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And finally the Compound Control. Note the line:

```
android:textColor="?attr/numberTint"
```

is what I'm not sure about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="?attr/numberTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="A"
    android:textColor="?attr/letterTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="?attr/numberTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="B"
    android:textColor="?attr/letterTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="3"
    android:textColor="?attr/numberTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="C"
    android:textColor="?attr/letterTint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know that I can suck the attributes up in the MyView.java class and manually set the textColor of the TextViews, but this feels dirty. I feel like I'm missing something simple. I also know that I could do this with styles but this also doesn't feel right.

How can I use the attributes directly in the compound view without parsing them in the code?

Comment: I'm curious about that too, but last time I tried it didn't work.